# How can I get this html code's by xpath for using selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I have an update button and in python, bot ı want to click this button but ı try many options but not working ı can't locate element by XPath. Please help me? Thanks for your help.

Note: I need to locate by using the text "Update" because a lot of buttons ı have on a webpage.

```html
<span class="a-spacing-top-small">
  <span class="a-button a-button-primary a-button-small sc-update-link" id="a-autoid-2">
    <span class="a-button-inner">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-action="update" class="a-button-text" role="button" id="a-autoid-2-announce" style="">Update
        <span class="aok-offscreen">Nike Academy 18 Rain Jacket Men's (Obsidian, M)</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: can you update the question with the code trial and error you facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate/`click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-button.a-button-primary.a-button-small.sc-update-link[id^='a-autoid'] a.a-button-text[id$='announce']>span.aok-offscreen"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-button a-button-primary a-button-small sc-update-link' and starts-with(@id,'a-autoid')]//a[@class='a-button-text' and contains(@id,'announce')]/span[@class='aok-offscreen' and starts-with(., 'Nike Academy 18 Rain Jacket Men')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-action,'update']")
```

Where driver is your instance of driver.